# Cheapest 1 month trips in next 3 months

Tags: air-travel

Google Flights lets you search for trips in a specific month or next 6 months. It also lets you search for 2 week trips at maximum.

I'd like to be able to search for 1 or 2 or 3 months trips instead of 2 weeks. Also in next 2 or 3 or 4 months instead of in next 6 months or in a specific month.

Is there a way to make this happen on Google Flights or is there website for this purpose?

Comment: have a look in skyscanner.net ?

Comment: Yes, it works similarly to Google Flights, except trip duration is random. So its worse than Google Maps

Comment: ITA matrix let's you search for arbitrarily trip lengths for one month at a time. So you may have to break in into 2 or three searches.

Comment: ITA matrix is horrible in my experience but maybe it might make sense for some routes